# Get updated id from entity autogenerate primary key

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel, android-room, android-viewmodel

I created Alarm class and annotate it as Entity on Android Studio.
In this class I have put id variable as Entity Primary Key and it is auto generate.

```
@Entity(tableName = "alarm_data_table")
class Alarm(

    @ColumnInfo(name = "alarm_hour")
    var alarmHour: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "alarm_min")
    var alarmMin: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "is_am")
    var isAM: Boolean,

    var days: ArrayList<Int>?,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "is_on")
    var isOn: Boolean,

    var label: String,

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int = 0
) {

    fun setAlarmSchOnOff(isOn: Boolean, activity: Activity){
        if (isOn){setAlarmScheduleOn(activity)}
        if (!isOn){setAlarmScheduleOff(activity)}
    }


    fun setAlarmScheduleOn (activity: Activity) {
        val alarmManager = activity.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        Log.d("ALARM ON", Integer.toString(id))
        val alarmIntent = Intent(activity, AlarmReceiver::class.java).let { intent ->
            intent.putExtra(Constants().ALARM_LABEL_KEY,label)
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                activity,
                id,
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            )
        }

        val calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
            timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
            set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmHour)
            set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmMin)
        }

        days?.let {
            it.forEach {
                calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, it) }
            alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(
                AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar.timeInMillis,
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR,
                alarmIntent
            )
        } ?:run{
            alarmManager.set(
                AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar.timeInMillis,
                alarmIntent)
        }
    }

    fun setAlarmScheduleOff(activity: Activity) {
        val alarmManager = activity.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        Log.d("ALARM OFF", Integer.toString(alarmId))
        val alarmIntent = Intent(activity, AlarmReceiver::class.java).let { intent ->
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                activity,
                id,
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            )}
        alarmManager.cancel(alarmIntent)
    }
}
```

The problem is every time I tried to retrieve id for setAlarm method it will always return 0.

```
2019-10-30 15:38:07.441 11066-11066/com.andreasgift.myclock D/ALARM ON: 0
```

Is there any way to return the id value after Entity update the value/ successfully insert it into table.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to return the id value after Entity update the value/
>   successfully insert it into table

1. Change to use (optional)

:-

```
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
var id: Long = 0 /*<<<<<<<<<< var not val + Long instead of Int */
```

- you should really use Long for id columns as

  - a) the SQliteDatabase **insert** method that is ultimately used, returns a long and
  - b) (which is why a is as it is)) a rowid (which is effectively what autogenerate uses ) can be a value larger then an Int can hold (i.e. a 64 bit signed integer).
- If you wanted to use Int for **id** then you could use `myAlarm.id = (alarmDao.insertAlarm(myAlarm)).toInt()` instead of `myAlarm.id = alarmDao.insertAlarm(myAlarm)`

And use a Dao

```
@Insert
fun insertAlarm(alarm :Alarm) :Long
```

- i.e. set it so that it returns :Long

The insert now returns the id (or -1 if the insert didn't insert the row). If you still use the Alarm object after the insert then you could use something like :-

```
    myAlarm.id = alarmDao.insertAlarm(myAlarm) /*<<<<<<<<<< SET THE id according to the inserted id */
```